# Problem with absolute values of the components of a vector

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I am stuck with the following problem.

By $$f_i \ll g_i $$ with $ f_i \ , \ g_i \in \mathbb{R}$ for all $i$ I mean that there is a constant $c$ such that $$|f_i| \leq c|g_i| \ \forall \ i .$$ Suppose that $a_1, \ldots , a_n$ are independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $g = (g_1, \ldots , g_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is such that $$|a_i \cdot g| \ll B \ \ (i= 1, \ldots , n).$$ where $\cdot$ is the usual scalar product. We write $$||g|| = \max(|g_1|, \ldots , |g_n|).$$ Then can we conclude that $$||g|| \ll B $$ ? Why ?

Comment: Do you mean for your vectors to have entries in $\mathbb R$ or entries that are functions in the variable $x$?

Comment: they have entries in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: If $a, b \in \mathbb R$ then $a \ll b$ just means that it is *not* the case that $a \neq 0$ and $b = 0$ (as $c$ can be chosen arbitrarily large).  So then you just have two cases to think about: $B = 0$ and $B \neq 0$.

Comment: @Jim: I have edited

Comment: $\ll$ means that there is a constant $c$ that verifies the relation for all $i$

Comment: Still simplifies to the statement that $g_i = 0$ implies $f_i = 0$.

Comment: Should $B$ be a vector now?  If you're comparing to the same number $B$ the whole time you still just have two easy cases, $B = 0$ and $B \neq 0$.

Comment: B is a number, so have you a solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f_i \ll g_i$ just means that for all $i$, $g_i = 0$ implies $f_i = 0$.  Thus if $B \neq 0$ then $\lVert g\rVert \ll B$ holds vacuously.  Now assume $B = 0$.  Then $|a_i\cdot g| \ll B$ means $|a_i\cdot g| = 0$, or equivalently, $a_i\cdot g = 0$ for all $i$.  As the $a_i \in \mathbb R^n$ are linearly independent they form a basis so this means $g = 0$.  In particular $\lVert g\rVert = 0$ so $\lVert g\rVert \ll B$ holds.